# Is it true that each number $2p>6, \ p \ is \ prime$ has a Goldbach partition which contains two twin primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For instance,

$$2\cdot 5 = 10 = 7+3$$
$$2\cdot 7 = 14 = 3+11$$
$$2\cdot 11 = 22 = 5+17$$
$$2\cdot 13 = 26 = 7+19$$
$$2\cdot 17 = 34 = 3+31=5+29$$

So, Is it true that each number $2p>6, \ p \ is \ prime$ has a Goldbach partition which contains two twin primes ?

Comment: $p=47$ is a counterexample, according to http://oeis.org/A007534

Comment: Do you know the random model for the primes. Assuming it we can estimate the distribution of twin primes and Goldbach pairs and find there are about $\sum_{k \le n}\frac{1}{\log^2 k \log^2 (2n-k)}\sim C\frac{n}{\log^4 n}$ twin Goldbach pairs for $n$. Thus for large $n$ enough it is plausible there is always one.

Comment: Is the partition $2p=p+p$ allowed if $p$ is a twin-prime ?

Comment: @Peter yes. Actually in would be interesting if you are able to proof that for each $2p_{twin1} >6$ $$2p_{twin1} = p_{twin2} + p_{twin3}$$

Comment: Note that in your "pattern" the twins are increasing. If it were true there would be infinitely many twin primes which is not known as far.

Comment: @Piquito We cannot expect a proof of this statement anyway because it probably won't be easier to be proven than Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: @Peter: What you say is the same as what I say but in other words.